# How to extract value before specific word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, discord, discord.js

I have a string called message, right now the message will be "Hello please press +enter to join our chat room"

```
let message = msg.toString()
```

the value before enter in this case + will always be different. My goal is, to extract the + before the enter.

My attempt was the following:

```
let position = message.search("enter")
let prefixlocation = position -1 
let prefixlocation2= position -3
let prefix = message.slice(prefixlocation, prefixlocation2)
console.log(prefix)
```

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciate it. Also if you have a quciker more convienient solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "Hello please press +enter to join our chat room";

str = str.replace("+enter", "enter");
console.log(str);

// or remove all +
str = "Hello please press +enter to join our chat room";
str = str.replace(/\+/g, "");
console.log(str);

// or remove any punctuation that occurs before enter
str = "Hello please press -$&*%%&&&enter to join our chat room";
str = str.split(" ").map(word => {
  let t = word.split('enter');
  return (t.length > 1 && !(/[a-zA-Z]/).test(t[0])) ? 'enter' : word;
}).join(" ")

console.log(str);
```

Comment: I dont know the value before "enter" could be + or something else

Comment: I just revised my answer for that. I assume it would be punctuation or some non-alpha character?

Comment: the problem is, it could be completly random, could also be a number or a letter or a && the only "static" part would be the word enter and that whatever be before that is the prefix

Comment: I updated my answer for this. I'm not sure how to make a regex for all the possibilities, so instead I map out the words, check for 'enter', make sure it's not part of another word (like reenter) and clean it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you want is to use enter as a marker

still using regular expression you can do a hunt for `press<whatever>enter`

```js
str = "Hello please press +enter to join our chat room";
str = str.replace(/press.*enter/g, "press enter");
console.log(str);
```

I recomend these to learn about regular expressions

https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

If the index position of press is always the same then search for the last occurrence of enter

```
var str = "Hello please press hello world enter to join our chat room";
var begin = str.indexOf("press") + 5;
var end = str.lastIndexOf("enter");

var extracted = str.slice(begin, end);

console.log(begin, end, extracted)
```